# Dates are not comparing

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to compare dates in my android application but it doesn't. It is always null.

Here is my code.

```
        GregorianCalendar startdate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 3, 3, 0, 00);
        GregorianCalendar enddate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 3, 4, 0, 00);

        for (int i = 0; i < newdate.length; i++) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MM/dd/yyyy k:mm");
                d[i] = formatter.parse(newdate[i]);

                if (startdate.equals(d[i])) {

                    startPoint = i;

                }
                if (enddate.equals(d[i])) {

                    endPoint = i;

                }

                // val2[i]=
                // DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
```

startPoint and endpont is always null. Can't I use equal method in this instance?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `GregorianCalendar#equals()` to check and because of the type of `d[i]` (i.e. `Date`) there's no equality (`GregorianCalendar` cannot be equal to `Date`).

Quick fix (not tested):

```
if (startdate.getTime().equals(d[i])){
    startPoint=i;
}
```